Question on constraints
Does there exist any set of 6 real numbers $a_{ij}$ for $1 \leq i < j \leq 4$ satisfying the following conditions:
\begin{aligned}
&0 \le a_{ij} \le \pi, \\
&a_{ik} + a_{jk} > a_{ij}, \\
&a_{ik} + a_{ij} > a_{jk}, \\
&a_{ij} + a_{jk} > a_{ik}, \\
&a_{ik} + a_{ij} + a_{jk} \leq 2\pi,
\end{aligned}
for $1 \leq i < j < k \leq 4$ but are not the angles between 4 rays in $\mathbb{R}^3$?
Thanks for any helpful answer.

Yes: I think you can fix $5$ angles out of $6$, with the given constraints, but the $6$-th is then determined.

@PietroMajer  Thank you for your comment. Then what should the additional inequalities or equalities be? Thanks.

I wrote it as an answer below. Is it clear enough?

For the angles between the planes $\pi_{12}$, $\pi_{13}$, and $\pi_{14}$, why can't it be the case that the sum of the first two angles equals the third angle?

In fact it could also be the case. In any case, it gives an affirmative  answer  to the initial question.

In other words, $5$ of the $6$ angles determine the position of the four unit vectors up an isometry, and up to a reflection. So there are only $2$ possible values for the last angle (one can also compute them) Is this clear? Does it answer the original question?

Let $\{x_i\}_{1\le i\le4}$ be given unit vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ with angles $a_{ij}:=\arccos(x_i\cdot x_j)$. Then the angle between the half-plane $\pi_{ij}:=\mathbb R x_i+ \mathbb R_+x_j$ and the half-plane $\pi_{ik}:=\mathbb R x_i+ \mathbb R_+x_k$, that is the angle between the projection of $x_j$ and $x_k$ on the plane  orthogonal to $x_i$, namely $\frac{x_j-(x_j\cdot x_i)x_i}{\|x_j-(x_j\cdot x_i)x_i\|}$ and $\frac{x_k-(x_k\cdot x_i)x_i)}{\|x_k-(x_k\cdot x_i)x_i\|}$, is
$$\arccos\frac{ (x_j\cdot x_k)-(x_i\cdot x_j)(x_i\cdot x_k)}{\sqrt{1-(x_i\cdot x_j)^2-(x_i\cdot x_k)^2+(x_i\cdot x_j)(x_i\cdot x_k)}}=$$
$$=\arccos\frac{ \cos a_{jk}-\cos a_{ij}\cos a_{ik}}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2 a_{ij} -\cos^2 a_{ik}+\cos^2 a_{ij}\cos^2 a_{ik}}} $$
(and it is bijectively determined by $a_{jk}\in[0,2\pi-a_{ij}- a_{ik}]$, once $a_{ij}$ and $a_{ik}$ are given).
Either the sum of the angles between the half-planes $\pi_{12}$, $\pi_{13}$,$\pi_{14}$ is $2\pi$, or one angle is the sum of the other two. In any case this gives an additional equality as a constraint. This is also sufficient to determine uniquely the position of the unit vectors $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ (up to rotations): to see it think to fix $x_1$. Then the three half-planes $\pi_{12}$, $\pi_{13}$, $\pi_{14}$ are determined (up to rotations) and we can therefore locate $x_2\in \pi_{12}$, $x_3\in \pi_{13}$, $x_4 \in \pi_{14}$ achieving the angles $a_{12},a_{13}, a_{14}$; the angles $a_{23},a_{24},a_{34}$ are then realised too because they are uniquely determined by the angles between the half-planes $\pi_{12}$, $\pi_{13}$,$\pi_{14}$.

How must the sum of the angles between the planes $\pi_{12}$, $\pi_{13}$,$\pi_{14}$  be $2\pi$?

By the "angle between $\pi_{ij}$ and $\pi_{ik}$" I mean exactly the angle between the projection of $x_j$ and $x_k$ on the orthogonal to $x_i$, namely $\frac{x_j-(x_j\cdot x_i)x_i}{|x_j-(x_j\cdot x_i)x_i|}$ and $\frac{x_k-(x_k\cdot x_i)x_i)}{|x_k-(x_k\cdot x_i)x_i|}$. These three angles sum to $2\pi$. I should have called  "angles between half-planes".

Why can't it be the case that the sum of the first two angles equals the third angle?

Right! I can be I think. So the additional constraint has to be stated in the form "either the sum of the three angles is $2\pi$ or the sum of two of them equals the third".
